# how do you make a shortcut that can select a file and run a DOS command with it as a parameter?

Tags: dos

I need this to be able to ask the user for a file, then after the user chooses one, it will run a CMD command like "program.exe [selected file]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking for a way to have a batch script create an open file dialog, I don't believe that's possible.  You're better off creating a small program that will do this for you.

Comment: I think there used to be a special "%" sequence one could put in a shortcut. Dunno if it still exists. There could be some dll callable by rundll that would do the trick. If not, one could make one. "Impossible" is a bit strong.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way, but I don't know it. I'm going to cover some alternatives.

GUIs work mostly by attaching commands to files, not the other way around. You can do that using file extensions. You can do that using Send To.

File extensions permit the association of an command (e.g. perl) with a file extension (e.g. .pl) Using "assoc" and "ftype", one associates the name to an extension, and a command to that name.

I'm not at my Windows machine at the moment, so I can't give you the exact usage. Type "help assoc" and "help ftype" at the prompt for usage. Use "%1" (quote included) in the command to indicate where the name of the clicked file should appear in the command.

Whenever you double-click on a file with that extension, it will be launched in with your command.

Alternatively, you can use "Send To". Somewhere in your profile is a directory named "Send To". (Just do a search to find it.) Put a shortcut to the application in there. To use the shortcut, right-click on the file you want to open, choose Send To, choose the application.

- Eric

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `cmd` command (the modern version of the DOS command line on Windows), which can invoke itself recursively. The command-line options are available by typing `cmd /?` at a command prompt.